# Javascript append doesn't seem to work correctly

Tags: jquery, append

I'm trying to randomly position 500 of the image "Smallstar.png" (and yes i know that it isn't well made yet, i just wanted to get functionality before going too deep), but the append feature in javascript doesn't seem to be appending to the div with the id prlx1.
I've tried using appendTo and prepend so I think that it is a problem with syntax, but i haven't been able to figure it out

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 for(i = 0;i<500;i++){
  var number =1+ Math.floor(Math.random()*100);
  var number1 =1+ Math.floor(Math.random()*100);
  var t= "<img id = 'imgs' src ='H:\Stars\Smallstar.png>";
  $("#prlx1").append(t); //This is where the problem is
  $("#imgs").css({marginLeft: number, marginTop: number1});
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Missing a closing ' and the \ need to be escaped

```
var t= "<img id = 'imgs' src ='H:\Stars\Smallstar.png>";
                                 ^^    ^^           ^^^
```

with the corrections

```
var t= "<img id = 'imgs' src ='H:\\Stars\\Smallstar.png'>";
                                 ^^     ^^            ^^^
```

Also makes no sense why you are not just using jQuery up front to set the styles

```
var img = $("<img/>")
              .attr("src","H:\\Stars\\Smallstar.png")
              .css({marginLeft: number, marginTop: number1});
$("#prlx1").append(img);
```

And you are probably are going to have an issue reading the file off the harddrive. Set up a local server and save yourself the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Id of an element must be unique...

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  for (i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    var number = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
    var number1 = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
    $('<img />', {
      src: '//placehold.it/32&text=' + i,
      css: {
        marginLeft: number,
        marginTop: number1
      }
    }).appendTo('#prlx1'); //This is where the problem is
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="prlx1"></div>
```